Can I not unlock Random with Menya Moonspell?
I know how to get Random since I read a guide:

 Open a coffin where you've opened one before

But I can't find the object when playing as Menya Moonspell? I know where it should be in Dairy Plant from this map:

 https://static0.gamerantimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/vampire-survivors-map.jpg

But the object's not there.
I don't already have Random, so that can't be why the object's not there, defended by enemies to be defeated before I can use it.

Yes, you either can't unlock Random with Menya, probably have to do it with a Base Game Standard Character or have to get all the others of "that" type first.

 Coffin characters

Because when using the last one of them, I saw the place on the Map. A.k.a:

 Using Zi'Assunta Belpaese, I saw the ? on the map in the Inlaid Library.

